# update mod-wsgi in apache on Ubuntu server

Tags: 12.04, apache2

I wish to update `mod-wsgi` to my Ubuntu server and I am doing it for the first time. I am not sure how do go about this. Can somebody guide me?

I tried `sudo a2enmod wsgi` but I am getting the following error.

```
ERROR: Module mod-wsgi does not exist!
```

I typed `sudo a2enmod` and these are the [choices](http://dpaste.de/NEIcf) I got!!
It does not contain `wsgi`. How should I go ahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi
```